# How to set struct fields throw interface?

Tags: reflection, struct, go

everyone!

My task is to parse command-line argument and fill struct fields. And my function must works with all kinds of arguments - they'll describe in struct tag.

For example:

```
type CommndLineArguments struct {
   Configfile string `required:"false" name:"config" default:"/etc/daemon.conf" description:"Config file"`
   Daemon     bool `required:"true" name:"daemon" default:"false" description:"Run as daemon"`
}
```

I use `reflect` and `flag` packages. Like this:

```
func    GetArguments(variable interface{}) error {
//Check is this a pointer to struct
variableType := reflect.TypeOf(variable)
if variableType.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
    return errors.New(ERR_PASS_BY_VALUE)
} else if variableValue := variableType.Elem(); variableValue.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
    return errors.New(ERR_NOT_A_STRUCT)
}

// Parse parameters

variableValue := variableType.Elem()

for i := 0; i < variableValue.NumField(); i++ {
    structField := variableValue.Field(i)
    fieldName := structField.Name
    fieldType := structField.Type
    fieldTag := structField.Tag
```

Now I'm ready to parse arguments.

```
switch fieldType.Kind() {
    case reflect.Bool:
        defaultValue, err := strconv.ParseBool(fieldTag.Get("default"))
        if err != nil {
            return errors.New(ERR_PARSE_ERROR + err.Error())
        }
        flag.BoolVar(&structField, fieldName, defaultValue, fieldTag.Get("description"))
```

But I get an error in last line.

`./parser.go:42: cannot use &structField (type *reflect.StructField) as type *bool in function argument`

My question is how can I set this field correctly?

Comment: Have you considered using https://github.com/jessevdk/go-flags ? It allows you to define flags based on a struct and struct tags.

Comment: Please format your code with `go fmt` or http://play.golang.org, it makes it easier for us to follow the code.

Comment: @elithrar +1, I'm using go-flags and it's awesome

Comment: @elithrar it is interesting package but I don't know what fields my struct will contain.

Comment: @DmitriyDemidov what do you mean you don't know? go-flags exposes the exact same API you want to expose, it works the way you want it already. Unless you're doing it for the educational value, there's no reason to write the same thing.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer yes, it is educational task

Comment: oh, in that case... can you post your entire code and I'll have a look at it?

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer you can see it here https://github.com/termith/cmd/blob/master/parser.go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to get the address of the field (also use `ValueOf` not `TypeOf`):

```
flag.BoolVar(fld.Addr().Interface().(*bool), fieldName, defaultValue, fieldTag.Get("description"))
```

Simple demo @ http://play.golang.org/p/yEG-OH6d4W

Comment: Keep in mind that you should check if the field is already a pointer or not.